# How to debug javascript in Visual Studio, loaded dynamically by ExtJS.Loader?

Tags: javascript, debugging, extjs, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.NET Visual Studio 2013 Project, and a lot of javascript files in app-extjs dir (controllers, viewmodels, ...)
My init code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
   enabled: true,
   paths: {
       'MyApp.controller': 'app-extjs/controllers',
       'MyApp.model': 'app-extjs/models',
       'MyApp.view': 'app-extjs/views',
   } 
});

Ext.application({
  name: 'MyApp',
  controllers: [
      'MyApp.controller.Root'
  ],
  autoCreateViewport: 'MyApp.view.main.Main',
});
```

How to debug javascript in visual studio, loaded dynamically by ExtJS.Loader?
My setConfig allows me load file, but I cannot debug it

Comment: why dont you use Chrome's debugger, I never use VS.Net's Javascript Debugger.

Comment: I tried. It works, but after changing the server side (ASP.NET), session is reset, need to open a new window and add brekpints again

Comment: just add debugger keyword in your code then. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#debugger

Comment: Yes, tried, thank you. Inconveniently - always need to refresh browser if line changes
but as an extreme option...

Comment: Agree with @hazimdikenli use Chrome. Once you have the dynamically loaded file you can edit in Chrome dev tools and see changes in the browser, add breakpoints, hover variables and see their values etc. Be sure to log XHR requests in the configurations(is a checkbox) of the developers tools.